# Tensorflow works but Keras is failed

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I have successfully install tensorflow-gpu and used it happily before,

but due to some reasons I didn't touch TF or Keras for a long time,

and then I got this error.

The error message is like this:

> `import keras`
>
> `from keras.layers import Dense`

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras.layers'

Note:

I used Anaconda to install this stuff.

But I'm sure it was not installed successfully

even if I checked the whether the package exists in anaconda prompt

However, when I tried to import tensorflow itself it is OK:

> `tf.__version__`
>
> '1.13.1'

The tensorflow is a gpu version.
These are the versions of the dependencies:

CUDA : 10.0

cudnn : 7.4

I have uninstall the tensorflow-gpu many times...

Can someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Did you try reinstalling keras

Comment: Did you actually install keras? How exactly?

Comment: In your version, keras did not come with tensorflow. You must install it

Answer (score 0):

Latest version of Tensorflow ~ 2.6.0 has in built Keras api.

```
!pip install tensorflow 
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
```